# react-native-beacons-manager Permissions.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, react-native, ibeacon, react-native-permissions

Using https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager

I still have error in console: `never_ask_again`
I still have Location Access Denied and don't know how to fix it.
What's is wrong.

My buildscript in `build.gralde` :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
```

I read that in this version in the Manifesto 'permissions' add yourself.
When I add manually permissions. `react-native run-android` delete this permissiosn.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, DeviceEventEmitter, ListView , Text} from 'react-native';
import Beacons  from 'react-native-beacons-manager';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {

    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
              'title': 'Location Permission',
              'message': 'Activeev needs to access your location.'
          }
      )
      console.log('here', granted);
      

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log("Location Permitted")
           // Start detecting all iBeacons in the nearby
            Beacons.detectIBeacons();

            Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion('one', '2cbe4ba8-1c4d-456f-9d43-6ab72499d99c').then((data)=>{   
                console.log(data);   
            })
            .catch((reason) => {   
                console.log(reason);   
            });

            // Print a log of the detected iBeacons (1 per second)
            DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('beaconsDidRange', (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });
      } else {
          console.log("Location permission denied")
      }

    }catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }

  }  

 render(){
   return(
     <View></View>
   );
 }

}
```

Comment: Do you ever see a dialog requesting the permission when you launch the app after an uinstall/reinstall?  If you go to Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Permissions and manually grant the location permission does it start working?

Comment: @davidgyoung I already did this and still the same problem. And i don't have dialog window